# How to output objects into my JTable so that editing a field affects the state of the original object?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a LinkedHashSet containing book objects. Everytime the application is opened it reads in the objects into the LinkedHashSet from a serialized file.

I was using an iterator to run through the LinkedHashSet and output the data of each objects fields into a multidimensional array to populate my JTable, but what happens is that if I click the editable Boolean column it is updating the array and not the original object?

How can I populate the JTable so that selecting the check Box changes the field of the actual object and then fire the table to update? (the table will then need to pull in the new data as that boolean field of the object sets another field.

Comment: Puce's answer is what your after, but you may want to take a read through [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), in particular [Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to implement a custom table model eg. based on a List.

Here is a List based read-only table model sample I once wrote:

http://puces-samples.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/puces-samples/tags/sessionstate-1.0/sessionstate-suite/sessionstate-sample/src/blogspot/puce/sessionstate/sample/ParticipantTableModel.java?revision=13&view=markup

Follow the tutorial to implement a writable table model:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: Thank you I have read that but am having trouble understanding, as I say I can populate the table with a multidimensional array but it causes the issue where the edit functionality does not do what I need.

Comment: Did you try to replace your multidimensional array approach with the List based table model approach I recommended? Where exactly do you have problems?

Comment: Ok I have followed your advice and have implemented those methods. as well as isCellEditable and getColumn Class.

so far so good. now when I click one of the check boxes how can I make it affect the field in that Book object, so if that field was a boolean = false, how can i make it change to true and update the table?

thank you :)

Comment: The tutorial I linked to also explains about firing events. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire Have you read that part? Do you have a specific question?